# USB Host Android Cannot Send String

Tags: java, android, arduino, usb, usb-otg

I wanted my Android to communicate  with an Arduino using an USB host. I've tried many references but can't seem to send any char to my Arduino. I can detect my Arduino but sending char or string to it is frustrating. Here are my codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
UsbDevice device=null;
UsbManager manager=null;
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
UsbInterface intf;
UsbEndpoint endpoint;
UsbDeviceConnection connection;
Button find;
Button send;
TextView hello;
UsbManager mUsbManager;

private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = 
"com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

private byte[] bytes;
private static int TIMEOUT = 0;
private boolean forceClaim = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Find);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send);
    hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hello.setText("");
            checkInfo();
        }
    });

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(device!=null) {
                intf = device.getInterface(0);
                endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
                connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
                hello.setText("Kirim");
                String kirim = "a";
                bytes = kirim.getBytes();
                connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
                connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.length, 0);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Device == 
null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });

private void checkInfo(){
    manager=(UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new 
Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),0);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver,filter);

    HashMap<String,UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    String i="";
    int j=0;
    while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
        device = deviceIterator.next();
        manager.requestPermission(device,mPermissionIntent);
        i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";
        j++;
    }
    hello.setText(i);
}
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        // call method to set up device communication
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "permission denied for device " + 
  device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

}
```

I iterate using a find button and send using a send button. The iteration went just fine, but the sending didn't work. I needed to send  just a character to the Arduino. My phone supports `OTG` and had been tested using other serial communication application to send char to Arduino and it works just fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

using the usb serial lib in releases section at: https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial then import the lib and install dependencies as shown in the url. For solving the problem you can create a service class that handles usb related stuff (look at usb host android documentation for details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html
as follows:

```java
public class UsbService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "UsbService";

    public static final String ACTION_USB_READY = "com.felhr.connectivityservices.USB_READY";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_ATTACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DETACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_NOT_SUPPORTED";
    public static final String ACTION_NO_USB = "com.felhr.usbservice.NO_USB";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_DISCONNECTED";
    public static final String ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING = "com.felhr.connectivityservices.ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING = "com.felhr.connectivityservices.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING";
    public static final int MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT = 0;
    public static final int CTS_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int DSR_CHANGE = 2;
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static final int BAUD_RATE = 9600; // BaudRate. Change this value if you need
    public static boolean SERVICE_CONNECTED = false;

    private IBinder binder = new UsbBinder();

    private UsbService context;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private UsbManager usbManager;
    private UsbDevice device;
    private UsbDeviceConnection connection;
    private UsbSerialDevice serialPort;

    private boolean serialPortConnected;
    /*
     *  Data received from serial port will be received here. Just populate onReceivedData with your code
     *  In this particular example. byte stream is converted to String and send to UI thread to
     *  be treated there.
     */
    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            try {
                String data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                if (mHandler != null)
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, data).sendToTarget();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * State changes in the CTS line will be received here
     */
    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbCTSCallback ctsCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbCTSCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCTSChanged(boolean state) {
            if(mHandler != null)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CTS_CHANGE).sendToTarget();
        }
    };

    /*
     * State changes in the DSR line will be received here
     */
    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbDSRCallback dsrCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbDSRCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDSRChanged(boolean state) {
            if(mHandler != null)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(DSR_CHANGE).sendToTarget();
        }
    };
    /*
     * Different notifications from OS will be received here (USB attached, detached, permission responses...)
     * About BroadcastReceiver: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
                boolean granted = arg1.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (granted) // User accepted our USB connection. Try to open the device as a serial port
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                    new ConnectionThread().start();
                } else // User not accepted our USB connection. Send an Intent to the Main Activity
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)) {
                if (!serialPortConnected)
                    findSerialPortDevice(); // A USB device has been attached. Try to open it as a Serial port
            } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)) {
                // Usb device was disconnected. send an intent to the Main Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
                arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                if (serialPortConnected) {
                    serialPort.close();
                }
                serialPortConnected = false;
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * onCreate will be executed when service is started. It configures an IntentFilter to listen for
     * incoming Intents (USB ATTACHED, USB DETACHED...) and it tries to open a serial port.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context=this;
        serialPortConnected = false;
        UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED = true;
        setFilter();
        usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        findSerialPortDevice();
    }

    /* MUST READ about services
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        serialPort.close();
        unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
        UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED = false;
    }

    /*
     * This function will be called from MainActivity to write data through Serial Port
     */
    public void write(byte[] data) {
        if (serialPort != null)
            serialPort.write(data);
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler mHandler) {
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }

    private void findSerialPortDevice() {
        // This snippet will try to open the first encountered usb device connected, excluding usb root hubs
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {

            // first, dump the hashmap for diagnostic purposes
            for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                device = entry.getValue();
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("USBDevice.HashMap (vid:pid) (%X:%X)-%b class:%X:%X name:%s",
                        device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId(),
                        UsbSerialDevice.isSupported(device),
                        device.getDeviceClass(), device.getDeviceSubclass(),
                        device.getDeviceName()));
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                device = entry.getValue();
                int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
                int devicePID = device.getProductId();

//                if (deviceVID != 0x1d6b && (devicePID != 0x0001 && devicePID != 0x0002 && devicePID != 0x0003) && deviceVID != 0x5c6 && devicePID != 0x904c) {
                if (UsbSerialDevice.isSupported(device)) {
                    // There is a supported device connected - request permission to access it.
                    requestUserPermission();
                    break;
                } else {
                    connection = null;
                    device = null;
                }
            }
            if (device==null) {
                // There are no USB devices connected (but usb host were listed). Send an intent to MainActivity.
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_USB);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "findSerialPortDevice() usbManager returned empty device list." );
            // There is no USB devices connected. Send an intent to MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_USB);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    private void setFilter() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_DETACHED);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED);
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
    }

    /*
     * Request user permission. The response will be received in the BroadcastReceiver
     */
    private void requestUserPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("requestUserPermission(%X:%X)", device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId() ) );
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPendingIntent);
    }

    public class UsbBinder extends Binder {
        public UsbService getService() {
            return UsbService.this;
        }
    }

    /*
     * A simple thread to open a serial port.
     * Although it should be a fast operation. moving usb operations away from UI thread is a good thing.
     */
    private class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
            if (serialPort != null) {
                if (serialPort.open()) {
                    serialPortConnected = true;
                    serialPort.setBaudRate(BAUD_RATE);
                    serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                    serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                    serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                    /**
                     * Current flow control Options:
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_RTS_CTS only for CP2102 and FT232
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_DSR_DTR only for CP2102 and FT232
                     */
                    serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                    serialPort.read(mCallback);
                    serialPort.getCTS(ctsCallback);
                    serialPort.getDSR(dsrCallback);

                    //
                    // Some Arduinos would need some sleep because firmware wait some time to know whether a new sketch is going
                    // to be uploaded or not
                    //Thread.sleep(2000); // sleep some. YMMV with different chips.

                    // Everything went as expected. Send an intent to MainActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_READY);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    // Serial port could not be opened, maybe an I/O error or if CDC driver was chosen, it does not really fit
                    // Send an Intent to Main Activity
                    if (serialPort instanceof CDCSerialDevice) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No driver for given device, even generic CDC driver could not be loaded
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in your main activity put this snippets:

```
java
 private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED: // USB PERMISSION GRANTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED: // USB PERMISSION NOT GRANTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_NO_USB: // NO USB CONNECTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No USB connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED: // USB DISCONNECTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED: // USB NOT SUPPORTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    private UsbService usbService;
    public TextView display;
    private EditText editText;
    private MyHandler mHandler;
    private final ServiceConnection usbConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
            usbService = ((UsbService.UsbBinder) arg1).getService();
            usbService.setHandler(mHandler);
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"dentro on service connected " + usbService, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            usbService = null;
        }
    };
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.operacion);
        mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
// your stuff here
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
   //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"on resume ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setFilters();  // Start listening notifications from UsbService
        startService(UsbService.class, usbConnection, null); // Start UsbService(if it was not started before) and Bind it
     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"despues de start y weas ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        unbindService(usbConnection);
    }

    private void startService(Class<?> service, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, Bundle extras) {
    //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED) {
            Intent startService = new Intent(this, service);
            if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {
                Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                for (String key : keys) {
                    String extra = extras.getString(key);
                    startService.putExtra(key, extra);
                }
            }
            startService(startService);
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"dp metodo start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent bindingIntent = new Intent(this, service);
        bindService(bindingIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void setFilters() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_NO_USB);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    }


    public void getCurrentTimeUsingDate(){
        String currentDateTimeString2 = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        TextView txtView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txtView3.setText(""+currentDateTimeString2);
    }

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<Pag4> mActivity;

        public MyHandler(Pag4 activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        Integer conta = 0;
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch (msg.what) {
                case UsbService.MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT:
                    String data = (String) msg.obj;
                    conta++;
  break;

                case UsbService.CTS_CHANGE:
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.get(), "CTS_CHANGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.DSR_CHANGE:
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.get(), "DSR_CHANGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

you make a button (btn3 in the example) and then add the listener as follows:

```
java
 bt3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String auxi2="1"; // put whatever you need to send here
                if (!auxi2.equals("")) {
                    String data = auxi2;

                    if (usbService != null) { // if UsbService was correctly binded, Send data
                        usbService.write(data.getBytes());
                     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"auxi2 escrito"+ auxi2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Hope is clear, I assume you know how to import libs, and make a button, put the permission in manifiest, dependencies. Details about this in android doc link already posted upper in my answer.